# create union function that returns type of set<int>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++14, discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble completing a function, currently does not let my program use `cout` when I am calling it in main. I am trying to find an alternative way to create a function definition for:

```
set<int> Union(const set<int> & s0, const set<int> & s1);
```

which creates and returns a set that is the union of two other sets (s0 and s1). What I have written (a function trying to use set_union method from #include ) and desired output is down below:

Desired output: 
Given set s0 has {1,2,3,4} and set s1 has {4,5,6,7}, a new set must be created (s3 that has {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}).
All help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
set<int> Union(const set<int> & s0, const set<int> & s1);
int main(){
set<int> s0{1,2,3,4};
set<int> s1{4,5,6,7};
cout << Union(s0,s1) << endl;
}
set<int> Union(const set<int> & s0, const set<int> & s1) {
    set<int> s; 
    set_union(s0.begin(), s0.end(),
        s1.begin(), s1.end(),
        s, s.begin());
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then edit your question to actually include a question. What is the problem you have with the code you show? What is the actual "output" you get? What did you expect?

Comment: What troubles do you have? Please specify.

Comment: please also fix the indentation, the code is unreadable

Comment: I can see 2 problems with your code: 1) output stream do not accept sets, 2) you need to use `std::inserter` as a last argument of `set_union`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `std::set_union` with `std::inserter` like this:

```
std::set<int> Union(const std::set<int> & s0, const std::set<int> & s1) {
    std::set<int> s; 
    std::set_union(s0.begin(), s0.end(),
        s1.begin(), s1.end(),
        std::inserter(s,s.begin()));

    return s;
}
```

And you will also have to define output stream operator for `std::set`.

```
template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<T>& v) 
{ 
    os << "["; 
    for (auto it : v) { 
        os << it; 
        if (it != *v.rbegin()) 
            os << ", "; 
    } 
    os << "]\n"; 
    return os; 
}
```

See [demo here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZkcbFG4ohonsaPUb).

Note: For MSVC compiler, `<iterator>` header should be included to use `std::inserter`.

Comment: When trying to use inserter(s,s.begin()) I get an error from the compiler stating inserter is not a member of std

Comment: Which compiler are you using? As shown in the demo, it should work. See if the header files are included correctly.

Comment: I am using visual studio to run the code, I made sure header files were included correctly

Comment: I'm not too sure, I know I am using MSVC 2017 and I can not use C++17

Comment: Have you included the `<iterator>` header in your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17, there is [`std::set::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/merge) for you. Note that this member function mutates both the object it belongs to and the function argument. Hence, changing the function signature of `Union` such that both sets are copied makes sense for an implementation that uses the `merge` function:

```
std::set<int> Union(std::set<int> s0, std::set<int> s1) {
   s0.merge(std::move(s1));

   return s0;
}
```